# Overlay two seaborn plots in jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to overlay 2 seaborn distplots in jupyter notebook. This code works if I use the normal python shell but doesn't work with Jupyter. I get only one graph. The second graph is not displayed.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
%matplotlib inline
sns.set()
sns.distplot(x['wr'], kde=False, label='16-4', hist_kws={"alpha": 0.2})
sns.distplot(y['wr'], kde=False, label='17-4', hist_kws={"alpha": 0.2})
plt.show()
```

Please don't suggest using the `hue` argument.

Comment: How does it not work? What are you getting?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested that this works on my sample data:

```
ax = sns.distplot(x['wr'], kde=False, label='16-4', hist_kws={"alpha": 0.2})
sns.distplot(y['wr'], kde=False, label='17-4', hist_kws={"alpha": 0.2}, ax=ax)
#                                                                       ^^^^^
```

But, actually, my code works with or without the `ax=ax`; so I'm curious to know if it will work for you.

Comment: Yeah it did work for me without the ax. There was some issues with my jupyter theme. Had to reset it to default after which it worked.